# sequence of functions and integral (very short question at the bottom of this text)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I had to study the convergence of the sequence of functions:

$f_n(x)=(1-x^2)^n $ for $ n \in \mathbb{N}^+ , x \in \mathbb{R}$

and say if it's true that:     $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} f_n(x) dx=0$.

---

i found out it converges pointwise to:

$ \bullet$ 1 if x=0

$ \bullet$ 0 if $-\sqrt{2} < x < +\sqrt{2}$

$ \bullet$ it oscillates between 1 (if n is even) and -1 (if n is odd) for $x= \pm \sqrt{2} $
Also, there doesn't exist an N such that the sequence converges uniformly in  $\mathbb{R}$. However it converges uniformly in all the compact subsets [a,b] or [c,d] where $ a>-\sqrt{2} , b<0 , c>0, d<-\sqrt{2}$

now, i know that if the sequence converges uniformly i can use the following theorem:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} f_n(x) dx$=$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}  f(x)$ where f(x) is the uniform limit.

However, in this case, I have discontinuity in 0 and +-sqrt2. can i split the integral in two on the left and on the right of 0, sum them and say it holds all the same? Or does the theorem fail before these circumstances?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First since the function $f_n$ is even we have
$$\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt2}f_n(x)dx=2\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}f_n(x)dx$$
second as you mentioned $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent on the interval $[\epsilon,\sqrt2-\epsilon]$ for every $0<\epsilon<\frac{\sqrt{ 2}}{2}$. Now write:
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}f_n(x)dx=\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\epsilon}f_n(x)dx}_{\le\epsilon}+\underbrace{\int_{\epsilon}^{\sqrt2-\epsilon}f_n(x)dx}_{I_n\to0}+\underbrace{\int_{\sqrt2-\epsilon}^{\sqrt2}f_n(x)dx}_{\le\epsilon}$$
hence, let $\epsilon>0$ and since $\lim_nI_n=0$ there's $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\forall n\ge N,\; I_n\le\epsilon$ hence 
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt2}f_n(x)dx\le 3\epsilon$$
and we can conclude.

Comment: Isn't $(f_n)$ only convergent on $[\epsilon,\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: The focus of my question was mostly at the $x=\sqrt{2}$, the right bound. $f_n$ is not convergent on closed $[\epsilon,\sqrt{2}]$ because at the right bound, $(1-2)^n = (-1)^n$ which never converges.

Comment: @ZackLi I edited my answer.